# Calling Oracle Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, callable-statement

I have a method that calls an oracle procedure at the same time as it inserts into oracle, the insert statement works but the procedure does not.  I am not receiving any errors. can anyone see why this isnt working?

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + oracle_ip_address + ":" + oracle_db_port + ":" + oracle_db_sid;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, oracle_db_username, oracle_db_password);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from Dropper"); 

CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call TTMS.job_vacationconflict_notify(?,?,?)}");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();

    while (rs.next()){
        String di = rs.getString("DROPPER_ID");
        String sd = rs.getString("BEGIN_DT").replace(" 00:00:00.0", "");
        String ed = rs.getString("END_DT").replace(" 00:00:00.0", "");
        String vi = rs.getString("VACATION_ID");
        String md = rs.getString("MODIFY_DT").replace(" 00:00:00.0", "");

        query = "INSERT INTO DROPPER_VACATIONS(DROPPER_ID, BEGIN_DT, END_DT, CREATE_DT, CREATE_BY, MODIFY_DT, MODIFY_BY, COMMENTS, VACATION_ID) "
        + "VALUES ('"+di+"',to_date('"+sd+"','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('"+ed+"','YYYY-MM-DD'),sysdate,'MJRUTLED',to_date('"+md+"','YYYY-MM-DD'),'MJRUTLED','','"+vi+"')";

        stmt2.executeUpdate(query);

        cs.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(di));
        cs.setString(2,sdf.parse(sd).toString());
        cs.setString(3,sdf.parse(ed).toString());

        cs.execute();
    }
```

Comment: "but the procedure does not" - Can you explain that?

Comment: the data is properly inserted into the table, but the procedure is not executed.

Comment: @Mike what are you doing to assume that the procedure is not executed? Can you give us some context of job_vacationconflict_notify?

Comment: @Perception the procedure is supposed to send an email, the procedure works properly, any print statements after the `cs.set` statements dont print anything

Comment: Looks like you're clobbering your dates as you pass them into your stored procedure call. You should probably just pass the strings `sd` and `ed`. Remember that calling `toString()` on a date just prints it out in the default format specified by the JDK, which is probably not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your procedure expect dates as input? If it does, try to pass date values and not rely on implicit conversion. If the SP expects strings, make sure you format the dates exactly the same way that the SP expects (add debug print on both sides, `dbms_output` and `dbms_pipe` are your friends).

Also, please consider using parameter substitution for `query`; this code *begs* for SQL injection %)

Comment: i changed the code so that it takes in dates and its still not working `cs.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(di));
 cs.setDate(2,(java.sql.Date)sdf.parse(sd));
 cs.setDate(3,(java.sql.Date)sdf.parse(ed));
 cs.execute(); `

Comment: check if date format is correct, I see 2 incompatible different formats : SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy") and 'YYYY-MM-DD' in your code